# can anyone help me out with this issue? i am new to flutter and learning to develop my interest please help me out in this

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, exception, build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
what went wrong:
could not open settings generic class cache for settings file'/Users/musadique/AndroidStudioProjects/testing_app/android/settings.gradle' (/User/musadique/.gradle/caches/6.7/scripts/f0emg6u6oecmxqzgk5g9nn4ui).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

Answer (score 1):

`I had this BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '...'` issue today and upgrading gradle (as mentioned in a comment) didn't work.

What worked for me was cleaning the gradle cache:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

and project gradle directory

```
rm -rf $PROJECT/.gradle/caches/ && rm -rf $PROJECT/build/
```